# Getting ConverterNotFoundException in basic springbatch program

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to create a springboot batch application and am getting below exception

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.Class<java.beans.PropertyEditor>>] for value '{org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.Range[]=org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.RangeArrayPropertyEditor}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.lang.Class<?>]

caused by 
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.lang.Class<?>]
```

It seems this error comes when spring tries to initialize org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer

I have not provide this bean definition in my code.

here are the key pieces of the code: 
A. Job definition (in XML):

```
<batch:job id="testBatchJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="step_test">
        <batch:tasklet  ref="createModifyTargetTable"/>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

B. other definitions (in java)

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:database-config.xml","classpath:batchflows-config.xml"})

public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(@Qualifier("metadata-db") DataSource dataSource,
                                       PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setDatabaseType("POSTGRES");
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Tasklet createModifyTargetTable(){
        return new CreateModifyTargetTable();
    }

}
```

Complete stacktrace

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.Class<java.beans.PropertyEditor>>] for value '{org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.Range[]=org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.RangeArrayPropertyEditor}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.lang.Class<?>]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:46) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:129) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1714) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1670) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) [spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:171) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.edci.datacopy.core.app.main.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.lang.Class<?>]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.MapToMapConverter.convertKey(MapToMapConverter.java:122) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.MapToMapConverter.convert(MapToMapConverter.java:84) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:40) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```